# Typescript is throwing a import statement formatting error where there is none because webpack needs that kind of formatting. How to stop this?

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm new to typescript and webpack and I'm trying to set up a project to learn how to use them together but typescript is showing an error that isn't one.

The "./testFunction.ts" part of my code is being highlighted as an error.

```
import testFunction from "./testFunction.ts";

console.log("imported function: "+testFunction());
```

The error:
An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './testFunction' instead.ts(2691)

But I need the .ts extension in order for webpack to detect this import and bundle it. My webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        mode: "development",
        entry: './src/index.ts',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: "bundle.js"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.txt$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
            ]
        }
    };
```

The { test: /.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" } part is what tells webpack what to load with ts-loader, if I omit the extension, how will webpack know what to bundle?

When I run the code with the .ts extension, it works fine, without it it throws:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './testFunction' in '***path***/src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 3:21-46
```

It's not a crippling error but it's annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specifying the extension, Webpack will look for a file with a `.js` extension.

If you want it to look for your TypeScript files, then you need to tell Webpack to also resolve `.ts` and `.tsx` extensions:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.txt$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```